# With mongo-go-driver, how do I efficiently retrieve duplicated field name from WriteError?

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

I have three unique indexes in my collection. When user accidentally insert a data having a duplicate in the field `B`, how do I know that the duplication comes from field `B`?
On unique index constraint violation, mongo-go-driver behavior is returning err `WriteException`, which basically consist of an array of WriteError and some other object.
The `WriteError` itself (from mongo-go-driver) :

```
// WriteError is an error that occurred during the execution of a write operation. This error type is only returned as part
// of a WriteException or BulkWriteException.
type WriteError struct {
    // The index of the write-in the slice passed to an InsertMany or BulkWrite operation that caused this error.
    Index int

    Code    int
    Message string
}
```

During a debug session, I found out that the value of the WriteError is :

```
{
    Index: 0
    Code: 11000
    Message: E11000 duplicate key error collection: auth.example index: B_1 dup key: { : "default-role-external-user" }
}
```

I know I always can infer the unique constraint violation via the `Code` (11000), but the library didn't provide a single field to retrieve the field name causing duplication error.

I know I can always parse the `Message` string as the last resort, but considering that Golang and MongoDB have been coexisting a long while and I'm sure I'm not the only one encountering this issue, I'm expecting the more robust and efficient way to retrieve the field name causing duplication error, which I'm yet to find.

Answer (score 1):

The short and saddening answer is that currently there isn't a better way with the official mongo-go driver.

Comment: Wait so devs actually use hackish way like parse the err message string to overcome this issue?

Comment: @icza This is the shortest answer I see from you !

Comment: @imeluntuk I don't know if they use this or not. It's rarely needed.

Comment: @Eklavya The asker posted a well-researched question and pretty much listed his / her viable options, and was asking if there is an easier way. And there is not. So I think currently this answer is what "there is to it".

Answer (score 0):

Applications that need to know whether a value in a unique field is already taken usually query the database for that value, rather than parsing the message returned by the server as you are asking.

This situation is not specific to MongoDB or Go - I am not aware of any MongoDB driver that parses unique index violations out of error messages, and I haven't heard of this being done for relational databases either.

Comment: True, but: If you check whether a unique value is already used before inserting a document, you're doing it wrong. You absolutely must do it after getting an insert error. Otherwise, you just created a race condition, because some other process could have inserted a conflicting document between your check and your insert.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, there is no structured info concerning this error, so we have to roll our own a bit. Note that parsing the error message relies on an implementation detail not a published API, which makes this a bit brittle. Have automated tests on hand that ensure this works!

## Index Setup

I'm creating a collection named "events" and configure an index on the "external_uuid" field within the documents. Note that the name ("unique_external_uuid_constraint") is given explicitly, exactly in order to search for it later on.

```bash
mongo --eval 'db.createCollection("events")'
mongo --eval 'db.events.createIndex({"external_uuid": 1}, {name: "unique_external_uuid_constraint", unique: true})'
```

## Error Handling

```golang
res, err := s.events.InsertOne(ctx, document)
if err != nil {
    // find out whether we actually have a MongoDB write error
    var write_exc mongo.WriteException
    if !errors.As(err, &write_exc) {
        return nil, err
    }

    // further dissect the write error:
    // E11000 seems to be MongoDB's "duplicate key error", a unique
    // constraint violation. We now only need to check the index
    // that prevented the insert, which we do by string matching.
    if write_exc.HasErrorCodeWithMessage(11000, "index: unique_external_uuid_constraint") {
        return nil, events.DuplicateEventUUID
    }
}
```